# Vim: how to manual fold indented block?

Tags: vim

How can I fold every line with the same indentation as the current line
(the line the cursor is on) using manual fold in vim?

Basically, sometimes I need Vim to fold things just as Vim would do when
`foldmethod=indent`, but I prefer work with `foldmethod=manual` and won't
change it.

For example:

```
function f(x)

  while (x > a)
    foo = bar
    someStuff() // suppose cursor is here
    x = foo + a
  end

  if (x < b)
    x = b // this line should not be indented
  end
end
```

In this case, it should fold lines `foo = bar` to `x = foo + a`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:-1,+1norm zF` to specify a relative range of lines to fold. (In
the case of 1 line above and one below you could omit the `1`s in that command
and just use `:-,+norm zF`).

If you're open to installing a plugin, there is
[vim-indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) which
gives 'indent objects' like `ii` for `i`nside `i`ndent and `ai` for `a`round
`i`ndent (among others). Then you could do something like `zfii`.